# Create filename rely on contents

Tags: sql, bash, awk

I have an SQL dump. I have processed its content using `sed` to produce current form.

```
7022,4749463839619600C700F700000000000101010....
9254,47494638396196008300F700000000003737373....
2613,FFD8FFE000104A4649460001020100C800C8000....
......
```

I want to produce multiple files with name of the file is the field before the colon (`7022`, `9254`, `2613`), and the extension is rely on the second field. If it begins with `4749` then the extension will be `.gif` else `.jpeg`. The content of the file is the reverse hexdumped second field.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse hexdumped"?

Comment: Show us your code, or even your efforts to do what you want.

Comment: I mean to create binary from hex dump. for example `xxd -r`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create the files using `awk`:

```bsh
$ ls
file.sql 

$ cat file.sql
7022,4749463839619600C700F700000000000101010
9254,47494638396196008300F700000000003737373
2613,FFD8FFE000104A4649460001020100C800C8000

$ awk -F, '{$2~/^4749/?f=$1".gif":f=$1".jpeg";system("xxd -r -p - "f"<<<"$2)}' file.sql

$ ls
2613.jpeg  7022.gif  9254.gif  file.sql

$ file 7022.gif 
7022.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 150 x 199

$ xxd 7022.gif 
0000000: 4749 4638 3961 9600 c700 f700 0000 0000  GIF89a..........
0000010: 0101 01                                  ...
```

Comment: I think he wants you to filter the resulting files with the command "xxd -r"

Comment: I think this is wrong, because you `print $2 > f` when you most likely should convert the hex representation to bytes.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann manu-fatto thanks for the clarification guys.

Comment: I just want to convert hex data back to binary. :) To get the original files back... Sorry for my bad english. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If perl is fine, you can use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $debug = 1;

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  my ($basename, $data) = split ',';

  my $ext = ($data =~ /^4749/) ? 'gif' : 'jpeg';

  my $filename = "$basename.$ext";

  print "writing data for $filename: $data\n" if $debug;

  my $bytes = pack "H*", $data;

  open (my $file, ">$filename");
  print $file $bytes;
  close $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
while read name data dummy; do
  m=${data:0:4}
  case $m in
    4749)
      ext=gif ;;
    *)
      ext=jpeg ;;
  esac
  xxd -r -p - $name.$ext <<<$data
done
```